# Recommended built-in WinXP language support for UTF-8 regex

Tags: regex, utf-8

It's my first foray into UTF-8 land. I'm an IIS Admin, so I've never gotten to touch this professionally. I'm trying to help a missionary who's translated the bible into an African language and now needs to do some global matching against large UTF-8 files. We're specifically matching for accented characters.

We're using older XP computers here, so I cobbled together a quick script in VBS knowing the language would be installed on their boxes already. After playing around for a few minutes, it appears VBS regexes handle UTF-8 by breaking each character up into 2 characters. To match a single â, my pattern is \u00c3\u00a2. Shouldn't this be \u00e2?

Since I'm out of my depth I thought I'd seek a little guidance. It almost looks like UTF-8 simply requires this kind of double matching (and UTF-8 is required.) Can someone tell me into which box canyon I'm coding? :-)

Downloading and installing Perl or Java is probably outside this project's bandwidth and technical know-how. The tool should be built in. MS Office is installed, so VBA is an option if there's some library that offers specific support. JavaScript is installed as well, though I don't know what versions.

Thanks

Comment: What you need to do is load the files with UTF-8 encoding. The Regex engine isn't likely to know anything about UTF-8.

Comment: I've verified I can open, read, and write the files. When I'm done Word opens them as UTF-8 files, just like it does the original files. I'm pretty confident I'm handling them in UTF-8 format. I'm using TristateUseDefault. I tried forcing TristateTrue, but that resulted in garbage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you need to match two or more consecutive dots (e.g. you have .. or ... in your regex but not .*) you can use any ASCII regex library on UTF-8 and expect it to work correctly.

The trick is to know what you are looking for. UTF-8 does that kind of byte breakup, so write your regex in whatever you are familiar with and convert it to UTF-8 and it will work unless it contains "..".

Comment: The trick indeed. I won't have .. in any of my expressions, so that's manageable. I'll need to identify every 2-character combination I'm searching for, though, right? It's doable, just challenging.

Comment: If I understand you correctly in the question your regexes are in Windows-1252 format. If so, save them in notepad, select format UTF-8, and open them in an old stupid text editor (e.g. Notepad from NT4) and extract the bytes.

Answer (score 0):

What about PowerShell? It uses the .NET regular expressions library, and that is one of the best libraries available, especially for Unicode support.

Comment: Great suggestion. I wish PS were installed on these systems. :-(